# Pass data from different class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm tring to pass the data of label to the LivePreviewActivity. Is there a better way to do this ? I don't know if the UIThread is working. I have also need the UIThread because i need to log the data continuously. For now the Log doesn't print on the console. My goal is accessing the label text on the Activity. Thanks. Please correct me if I'm doing this wrong. This is a quick-start project MLKit on Firebase. Any help will be wonderful. I have also need the UIThread because i need to log the data continiously.

```
class LivePreviewActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        OnItemSelectedListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

var labelName: String? = ""

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_preview)

        runOnUiThread {
            Log.d("LivePreviewActivity", labelName)
        }
    }
```

ImageLabelProcessor

```
class ImageLabelingProcessor : VisionProcessorBase<List<FirebaseVisionImageLabel>>() {

    val livePreviewActivity = LivePreviewActivity()

        for (label in labels) {
            livePreviewActivity.labelName = label.text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of passing values to Activities is via the intent you used to create the Activity. You shouldn't be creating Activities directly, as they have lifecycles.

```
val intent = Intent(context, LivePreviewActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(labelKey, labelValue)
```

where context is your current Activity, labelKey just a little const your will use for a lookup, labelValue your value you want to set.

and then in your activity's onCreate, you look up the extra using the bundle.

Hope this helps and that I understood your question correctly!